# Алгоритм Евклида на ассемблере и знаковые числа

Tags: алгоритм, ассемблер

Надо запрограммировать на любом языке довольно сложный алгоритм теории чисел, в котором используется около шести более простых алгоритмов. Я застопорился на реализации алгоритма Евклида на асме: с положительными числами он работает правильно, но на числах со знаком зацикливается. Что здесь не так?

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib


; Вычисление наибольшего общего делителя
gcd proto

.data
    ifmt db "%d", 0
    sfmt db "%s", 0
    dfmt db "%d %d", 0dh, 0ah, 0
    enter_a db "Enter a: ", 0
    enter_b db "Enter b: ", 0
    msg_gcd db "GCD = %d", 0dh, 0ah, 0
    a   DWORD ?
    b   DWORD ?

.code
start:
    .repeat
        ; Вводим два целых числа
        invoke crt_printf, ADDR sfmt, ADDR enter_a
        invoke crt_scanf, ADDR ifmt, ADDR  a
        invoke crt_printf, ADDR sfmt, ADDR enter_b
        invoke crt_scanf, ADDR ifmt, ADDR  b
        call gcd
        invoke crt_printf, ADDR msg_gcd, eax
    .until a == 0Dh
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

    ; Вычисление GCD
    gcd proc
        mov eax, a
        mov ecx, b
        .while eax != 0 && ecx != 0
            xor edx, edx
            .if SDWORD PTR eax > ecx
                idiv ecx
                xchg eax, edx
            .else
                xchg eax, ecx
                idiv ecx
                xchg eax, edx
            .endif
        .endw
        add eax, ecx
        ret
    gcd endp
end start
```

Comment: Вы же написали, что на _"любом языке программирование"_, а при этом выбрали _asm_ - вы легких путей не ищете :)

Comment: Я не понял зачем вы делите то a/b то b/a для отрицательных. Вообще НОД отрицительных чисел равен НОД их модуля, так что знак уберите и работайте как с положительными. Тут вот заглянул в гугл и _первое_ что попалось https://habrahabr.ru/post/205106/  там как раз статья про зацикливание классических алгоритмов НОД для отрицательных чисел :)

Comment: "Я не понял зачем вы делите то a/b то b/a для отрицательных" Использования аксиомы о том, что gcd(x, y) = gcd(x, y mod x). Перед этим просто делаю проверку, какое число больше. Интересно, вычисление gcd вычитанием будет работать быстрее или нет?

Comment: А причем тут вычитание, я просто предлагаю взять модуль и не парится, потому как отрицательные числа по понятным причинам меньше положительных и ecx=-1 будет меньше eax=10 и вы будете бесконечно делить 10 на -1

Comment: Про вычитание сказал к тому, что такой алгоритм мог бы оказаться быстрее, чем деление, которое медленное. Про модуль хорошая идея, так и сделаю.

Answer (score 1):

Используй такой код как основу:

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
  if(b==0)
    return a ? a : 1;

  while(1)
  {
    if(!(a%=b)) return b;
    if(!(b%=a)) return a;
  }
}
```

Comment: Я подумывал о том, чтобы дизассемблировать какой-нибудь алгоритм gcd на си и переделать для себя, но решил сначала в проблемах своей реализации разобраться.

Comment: @typemoon, а если не дизассемблировать, а этот переписать самому на ассемблер? Тут вроде всё просто - только несколько сравнений с нулём - от отрицательности никак не зависит. А у тебя какое-то сравнение на `>` в коде - вероятно, в нём и ошибка.